# Networkx and GIS, connecting separate node/edges to larger set of node/edges

Tags: python, gis, networkx, shortest-path

I have a small piece of GIS that looks to have about 5 separate parts. I am fairly new to networkx and can implement shortest path, but I need to find the shortest path between what is essentially 3 of the 5 separate parts. Is this even possible? In the example below, I need to get the shortest path from yellow to green via purple (pic below).  [The sample GIS files are from Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gbJ80dx961L1B9F8raEyNSBHNVfelFVB/view?usp=sharing)

The code I've used to attempt to get this follows, but gives me the error - `NetworkXNoPath: No path between (-80.37664150098621, 25.798887088817054) and (-80.37572950230658, 25.798888677059043).`  I get it, it's because the parts are not connected to the whole (purple), but can they be connected somehow (by adding nodes and edges) and a distance retreived? Or, is this something that should be done in preprocessing (GIS) so that the objects can be interpreted properly for shortest path?

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.read_shp('doral27thStreet.shp')
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(doralGDF,pos,node_color='k')

path = nx.shortest_path(G,source=list(G)[22],target=list(G)[1])
path_edges = zip(path,path[1:])
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,nodelist=path,node_color='r')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image: green2Yellow]

Comment: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.add_edge.html

Comment: I see that it's possible that it's to add nodes. How to id and add the nodes so that the graph has 1 single part?

Comment: I don't think it's possible directly from networkX. Or you would have to use machine learning to predict the shortest path and then link it there...

Comment: Yeah, this is looking more and more like preprocessing/GIS problem